# Robocopy destination to ZIP

Tags: xml, windows, powershell, robocopy

I'm trying to make robocopy send the files it's copying to a zip folder as a destination. Is this possible?

```
robocopy $src $dest $files /s
```

Is it possible to make the $dest a zip folder?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't specify an archive as a destination for robocopy.  Windows Explorer has a custom provider that allows you to treat zip archives almost like folders, but this feature is typically only accessible to programs that use common Windows dialogs.

If you need to archive a folder from the command line, I recommend `7z.exe`, which is part of [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/).